# Use Entity fields access with m prefixed fields but still use eg findByName instead of findByMName in spring-data

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have JPA entities with fields like String mName.
When using Spring data repositories I want to use e.g findByName instead of findByMName. I know that I can set the entity access to on properties instead of fields but that has other drawbacks.

Answer (score 2):

Use this way in your repository

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM Todo t where t.mName = ?1")
Todo findByName(String mName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create default method in Interface Repository like this :

```
@Repository
public interface TodoRepository extends CrudRepository<Todo, Integer> {

    default Optional<Todo> findByName(String mName){
        return findByMName(mName);
    }

}
```

Then you can call repo.findByName(mName).